# Polar and Cartesian coordinates in Poincare disk model.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I wonder if we can say that, similar to Euclidean 2D space, there are two equivalent views on the coordinates of the points, Cartesian $(x,y)$ and Polar $(r, \phi)$ with correspondence:

$$x = r\cos\phi$$
$$y = r\sin\phi$$

Or, there is no such 2 views on coordinates in Poincare disk? Or maybe, their correspondence is different?

Note, that my question is not about matching between Euclidean and Hyperbolic spaces, but rather on the view solely in Poincare disk.

Comment: The space underlying the Poincare disk is just the unit disk, and one certainly has the usual Cartesian and polar coordinate systems there---they don't depend on the metric imposed on that space.

Comment: @Travis okay, but can we say that it has the same relationship between polar and cartesian as in Euclidean space?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that since the coordinate systems do not depend on the metric, then neither does the relation between them.

Comment: @Travis Interesting. I guess that also implies that inner product in Poincare disk can be seen as $r_1r_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)$, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking that doesn't make sense, as an inner product is defined on a vector space. But at any rate, specifying an inner product (say on the copy of $\Bbb R^2$ in which the disk is embedded) introduces a metric structure, and again the coordinates are not dependent on this structure.

Comment: But can't we say points in Poincare disk can be presented as vectors, and hence, it is also a vector space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66826/discussion-between-sergey-ivanov-and-travis).